# iPhone UITableView Controller shows last item on the startup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

UITableView shows last item on the startup. How do I view the first item on the startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call following method to position your table view to any cell that you want:

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

For example,

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: It works but I could see the transition. For example once it load it was on the last index position and then it changes to first position. Is there any way I could do this on load?

Comment: I found it! I put the animation to NO and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I experiencing another issue, when I scroll tableView, it put back on top! Any help?

Comment: Where are you calling that method? You would rather call it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.